# The parent content type specified by content type identifier 0x0101 does not exist error in SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type

[image]Getting "The parent content type specified by content type identifier 0x0101 does not exist." while activating "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature on my site.

Also i observed that

"Site Content Type" section does not contain any content type.

Comment: Is it a production server? Can you do an iisreset?

Comment: I ran SharePoint configuration wizard as well as restarted the server but still same issue.

Comment: I succeeded to activate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" by using below powershell command:  Enable-SPFeature -Identity publishingSite -url $url -force                                                             Enable-SPFeature -Identity publishingresources -url $url  -force.                     But still not able to get any content types under "Site Content Type" section.

Comment: One More Update:  While activating "SharePoint Server Publishing" feature in Site features , getting below error:   Content type '0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39' not found in web 'URL of site'.    In log, getting below error "Failed to get all (feature-driven) content types.  This web front-end is not joined to the farm.   Failed to get the content type elements. #5008a: Failed to compare two elements in the array.